# Difference across crosstab

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, crosstab

I am calculating the shares across two dimensions (lets say product type and region) for individual years:

```
for year in years:
    subset = df[df["year"] == year]
    total_value = subset["Sales"].sum()
    test = pd.crosstab(subset["region"], subset["type"], values= subset["Sales"], aggfunc='sum')
    test = test.div(total_value)
    test = test.mul(100)
    test = test.fillna(0).applymap('{:,.2f}'.format)
    test = test[test.columns].astype(float)
```

I am getting something like this (shares per year):

```
               P1      P2     P3      P4      P5
East          7.87   0.19    3.62   18.03    4.21
North         2.61   0.00    1.43    2.72    1.58
South         4.86   0.00    3.28    4.36    5.02
West          8.56   0.00    7.30   14.34   10.01
```

However, now I want to calculate the share differences per year and get the average difference for different time periods (e.g. year1-5, vs. year6-10).

I would know how to do it in a 1d form, but for that I would have to create a single column for every row/column combination. However, the final output I need again as a 4x5 dataframe.

Comment: a `4x5` frame for each year?

Comment: No, but the average difference for different time periods should be in this format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, per your approach, you can store all the annual data in an array and work on that.

But better yet, create a double-index dataframe:

```
# toy data
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': np.random.randint(2010,2020, 1000),
                   'region':np.random.choice(['E','N','S','W'], 1000),
                   'type': np.random.choice(range(5), 1000),
                   'Sales': np.random.randint(0,100, 1000)})

# annual sale by number
new_df = df.groupby(['year','region','type']).Sales.sum().unstack('type')

# annual sale percentage
# unstack is for difference and rolling
new_df = new_df.div(new_df.sum(1), axis='rows').mul(100).unstack('region')

# now we take difference Y-o-Y and sum over rolling 5 years
new_df = new_df.diff().abs().rolling(5).sum().stack('region')
```

Output:

```
type                 0          1          2          3           4
year region                                                        
2015 E       44.474332  64.931846  61.957656  30.060912   45.492996
     N       36.204057  52.299241  45.474781        NaN  109.632937
     S       39.698786  83.768715  27.301780  40.782696   36.904007
     W       49.670535  66.442188  72.853962  64.791541   41.014700
2016 E       38.388212  65.782743  50.332091  29.604978   59.610948
     N       29.523157  39.702785  46.555568        NaN   74.166048
     S       31.292163  91.905342  22.590774  48.125503   40.766833
     W       43.356486  49.935648  61.237368  61.780280   48.403081
2017 E       29.999764  50.469091  53.820935  21.917220   63.225173
     N       23.144194  44.182024  56.224184  73.611386   47.923053
     S       39.958449  97.206148  36.318395  38.854843   48.255563
     W       39.394688  44.748035  61.690934  40.369818   52.724580
2018 E       44.147129  60.643527  52.280244  35.161092   79.539544
     N       30.314490  30.613567  38.863245  88.982652   39.505871
     S       43.003287  78.883680  62.720196  46.120358   47.269314
     W       53.430137  53.121051  59.104072  34.959932   56.230274
2019 E       39.953920  69.182441  30.876777  51.356302   94.883691
     N       56.479921  30.338623  49.644488  83.042179   25.614797
     S       55.892248  47.252970  65.340297  44.674311   32.825135
     W       61.341875  43.624507  50.857851  26.915145   83.036502
```

With this output, the last 5 years average ending in 2019 is:

```
new_df.loc[2019]
```

which gives

```
type            0          1          2          3          4
region                                                       
E       39.953920  69.182441  30.876777  51.356302  94.883691
N       56.479921  30.338623  49.644488  83.042179  25.614797
S       55.892248  47.252970  65.340297  44.674311  32.825135
W       61.341875  43.624507  50.857851  26.915145  83.036502
```

Answer (score 0):

This is great! However, there is a small correction. The shares should not be summed by row (which would be by region), but by year (the whole df sums to 1). For some reasons, `.unstack()` does not work for me in the chain to achieve this. Therefore I had to change the second row to:

```
new_df = new_df.unstack('region')
new_df = new_df.div(new_df.sum(1), axis='rows').mul(100)
```